# Return part of string using Regex

Tags: regex, webloadui

I'm looking for some regex to retrieve the GUID from the following URL

```
GetUploadedUserAudioIdfriendlyName=eb0c5663-a9c3-4321-8c0e-5ffbfb3139fc
```

I've so far got

```
GetUploadedUserAudioId\?friendlyName=([A-Fa-f0-9-]*)
```

but this is returning the full url

This is the image of where the expressions are to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.
[image]

Comment: What tool/language do you use ?

Comment: And what **part** of the string do you want?

Comment: This question makes no sense if you don't precise how you use the regex. Try this in the console of your browser :  `'GetUploadedUserAudioIdfriendlyName=eb0c5663-a9c3-4321-8c0e-5ffbfb3139fc'.match(/GetUploadedUserAudioIdfriendlyName=([A-Fa-f0-9-]*)/)`

Comment: You're halve way there. You need to get the first capture group from the result to get the part you want.

Comment: And what is with the `\?` in your pattern?

Comment: I only need the GUID part which is the string after the = sign. I need to use the expression in WebLoadUI so I can create a variable and pass it to another url.

Comment: Ikke is right. Your regex gets everything that matches the entire pattern which includes the bit preceding the GUID. The GUID is caught in your first capture group which is normally accessed with a `\1` but may vary in some languages.

Comment: what tool/language are you using.some1 can come up with better solution then using regex..so please specify it

Comment: Generally you're not looking for the match, your looking for a *captured group* within the match, i.e., something inside parenthesis in your regex. How you get at this depends on the language you're using.

Comment: FYI: You might find this site useful for testing regex: http://regex101.com/r/uC9tD2

Comment: The tool is WebLoadUI.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regex for this.

Assuming you're using C#.NET, use the static `ParseQueryString()` method of the `System.Web.HttpUtility` class that returns a `NameValueCollection`.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?GetUploadedUserAudioIdfriendlyName=eb0c5663-a9c3-4321-8c0e-5ffbfb3139fc");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) documentation

---

**EDIT**: If you want it as a Guid after that, then cast it to one:

```
var paramGuid = new Guid(param1);
```